# Adding text into a double mustache using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to Vue and trying to learn. I have an object:

```
info: [
  {
    email: "newperson@xyzc.edu"
  }, {
    Initial: "Initial Biosketch"
  }
]
```

How do I load values into the html?  I have tried  `{{email}}` and `{{info[0]}}` and `[[infor.email}}` and `{{infor["email"]}}`.  Nothing seems to work.  `info[0]` works a little it gives me `"email": "newperson@xyzc.edu"`.

Comment: where is that info variable stored?

Comment: *'I have an object'*. While this is true it is more accurate to say that you have an array containing two objects, each with a single property. It is important that you understand that. On the face of it this is a strange choice of data structure. Within the `{{ ... }}` the usual rules of JavaScript apply, the only special Vue behaviour here is that it exposes the component's properties so you don't need the `this.`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `{{ info[0].email }}` and `{{ info[1].Initial }}` and plus you are using the wrong variable name here

`{{ infor['email'] }}`

Answer (score 0):

If the `info` property is not dynamic and not required to be an array it would be easier to struct it as an object. Try using object structure instead of array like:

```
info: {
  email: "newperson@xyzc.edu",
  initial: "Initial Biosketch"
}
```

and then use it in the template like `{{ info.email }}` and `{{ info.initial }}`